# Lookup in MongoDB doesn't compare with foriegn key _id

Tags: java, mongodb

```
/*first Table*/
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("orgmembers");

/*second table*/
        DBObject lookupFields = new BasicDBObject("from", "orgcenters");
        lookupFields.put("localField", "mappings.centerId");
        lookupFields.put("foreignField", "_id");
        lookupFields.put("as", "collegeDetails"); 
        DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("$lookup", lookupFields);
```

orgcenters schema

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5496d0a50cf2abd6b103b1a2"), "code" : "CEN-DVG", "name" : "Davangere"}
```

orgmember schema

```
{ "dob" : "1989-01-13", 
  "firstName" : "Sandeep", 
  "mappings" : [ { "programId" : "5496d0cd0cf2abd6b103b1a6", "centerId" : "5496d0a50cf2abd6b103b1a2"}] 
}
```

> Lookup in MongoDB doesn't compare with foriegn key _id

Comment: orgcenters table has { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5496d0a50cf2abd6b103b1a2"), 
    "code" : "CEN-DVG", 
    "name" : "Davangere",
}

Comment: orgmember table has { 
  "dob" : "1989-01-13", "firstName" : "Sandeep", "mappings" : [
        {
            "programId" : "5496d0cd0cf2abd6b103b1a6", 
            "centerId" : "5496d0a50cf2abd6b103b1a2", }],}
}

Comment: Even though your code is incomplete, so that I can only do a rough guess that you want to aggregate these collections and maybe do it correctly or not, one mistake is immediately obvious: the centerId in orgmember is a string, whereas the _id in orgcenters is an ObjectId. This will not match - you need to use the same data type.

Comment: yes.. I am matching _id(ObjectID) with centerId(String). How can I convert before matching ? Because it reads _id from db directly.. Pls help me out...

Comment: I added lookupFields = new BasicDBObject("from", "orgcenters");
   lookupFields.put("localField", "{$toObjectId: $mappings.centerId}");
   lookupFields.put("foreignField", "_id");
   lookupFields.put("as", "collegeDetails");
   DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("$lookup", lookupFields);  //still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

> If your localField is an array, you’ll need to add an $unwind stage to
>   your pipeline. See the example on this page. Please see [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

In `orgmember schema` we have mappings as an array and hence it has to be unwinded before executing the $lookup.

This query will work if we have both the id's as string

Note: Please change both the id's to String.

```
db.orgmember.aggregate([
{
   $unwind : "$mappings"
},
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "orgcenters",
       localField: "mappings.centerId",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "collegeFields"
     }
}])
```

In your query you have missed the $unwind option, thats why you are not getting the result.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: I added lookupFields = new BasicDBObject("from", "orgcenters"); lookupFields.put("localField", "{$toObjectId: $mappings.centerId}"); lookupFields.put("foreignField", "_id"); lookupFields.put("as", "collegeDetails"); DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("$lookup", lookupFields); //still didn't work